# How can I add child nodes to a treeview with deciding the depth level?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Treeview_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
        int numberofroots = 1000;
        int childsnum = 50;
        int leveldepth = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AddNodes();
        }

        private void AddNodes()
        {
            advancedTreeView1.Nodes.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberofroots; i++)
            {
                advancedTreeView1.Nodes.Add("New Node " + i.ToString());

                TreeNode subnode = advancedTreeView1.Nodes[i];

                if(allRootsWithChilds.Checked)
                {
                    subnode.Nodes.Add("New Node " + i.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i < childsnum)
                    {
                        subnode.Nodes.Add("New Node " + i.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void allRootsWithChilds_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                AddNodes();
        }
    }
}
```

Now if the checkbox is checked it will add one child to all the root nodes. All the 1000 root nodes will have one child. If unchecked only the first 50 root nodes out of the 1000 will have one child.

What I want to do now is if the checkbox is checked or not the root nodes that have once child I want to decide the depth level. For example if the depth level is 1 then the first 50 root nodes or all the root nodes will have one child.

But if the depth level is for example 4 then each of the root nodes if it's 50 or all of them will have 4 childs :

```
Node0
  Node1
    Node2
      Node3
        Node4
Node1
  Node1
    Node2
      Node3
        Node4
....
Node49
  Node1
    Node2
      Node3
        Node4
```

The variable childsnum decide how many root nodes will have childs.
The variable leveldepth should decide how deep to add childs to each root node.
And then I want to add another int variable to decide on each level how many childs to have.

For example in level 3 there will be 50 nodes for each root node.
And at level 1 there will be only 1 node for each root nodes.

Comment: When you have two separate `if` statements that both have the same body, you can combine the clauses: `if(allRootsWithChilds.Checked || i < childsnum) subnode.Nodes.Add("New Node " + i.ToString());` Then you only have to update the block of one `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you're missing is the logic to continue to add children to the next node. All you have to do is create another loop based on the value of `leveldepth`, and continue to set `subNode` equal to `subNode.Nodes[0]` in the loop.

Note that we can also use the return value of `Nodes.Add` (which is the node we just added) to set our `subnode` variable:

```
private void AddNodes()
{
    advancedTreeView1.Nodes.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRoots; i++)
    {
        TreeNode subnode = advancedTreeView1.Nodes.Add("New Node " + i);

        if (allRootsWithChilds.Checked || i < childCount)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < depthLevel; j++)
            {
                // Add a new child node and set subnode to the new node we just added
                subnode = subnode.Nodes.Add(subnode.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working nice. But I think in logic that when the depth level for example is 4 then if we take root node0 the childs should be numbered like this : Node0 > Node0 > Node0 > Node0 > Node0 since in each level there is only one node so at this level it's the first node each time. For example at level 1 it should be Node0 also at level 2 Node0 now each level child node have increased number : Node0 > Node1 > Node2 > Node3 > Node4 How can I change it ?

Comment: Just use `i` instead of `j` when assigning the node text if you want the child node number to match the parent (is that what you're asking?). Also, that's not what you have in your sample output above...Perhaps if you update your question to include the desired format for the output it would be helpful.

Comment: I updated the answer to give output like you asked about by specifically using the `subnode.Text` to set the child value. Also simplified the code a little to use the return value of the `Add` method to set our `subnode` variable.

Comment: Now if for example the level depth is 5 then for example on root node5 it will be like Node5 > Node5 > Node5 > Node5 > Node5 > Node5 and if it's for example Node4 then it will be Node4 > Node4 > Node4 > Node4 > Node4 > Node4 instead 0 in all childs.